# How to set language for a extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm developing Drupal modules using Visual Studio Code.

`.module` is php code, but VS Code cannot regconize it.

How could I set highlight for all `.module` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file association in you user settings and restart vscode:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.module" : "php"
}
```